# $E(Y\mid X)$ and $E(Y\mid X=x)$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I know that from measure-theoretic probability, $E(Y\mid X)$ and $E(Y\mid X=x)$ are different in nature: the former is "conditional on a random variable" and the latter is "conditional on an event" (let's assume it is a null event here). But I am still not sure about a few things:

1. When the two are equivalent, i.e. one implies the other?
2. If I specify $E(Y\mid X)=X$ and $E(Y\mid X=x)=x$, are the two equations equivalent, i.e., one implies the other?
3. When discussing, e.g., Statistical models like linear regression, we often write $E(Y\mid X)=X\beta$. In this case, are we using "conditioning on random variable" or "conditioning on event"? (This question will be trivial if the answer to question 2 is yes).

Comment: yes, but the later can be seen as a function of $x$. And my question is when one form can be derived from the other.

Comment: $E(Y\mid X=x)$ exists almost everywhere for each $x$, where the exceptional set may depend on $x$.  If you have uncountably many $x$ the conditioning may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The expression $X=x$ identifies a particular *event*, i.e. a particular subset of a probability space, and one conditions on *events*, speaking of conditional probabilities given an particular event, and therefore of conditional probability distributions given an event, and therefore of conditional expected values given an event.

The conditional expected value $\operatorname E(Y\mid X=x)$ is a conditional expected value given an event. What number it is depends on what number $x$ is. So it's a function of $x.$ Call it $g(x).$ We have $\operatorname E(Y\mid X=x) = g(x).$

Then $\operatorname E(Y\mid X)$ is the *random variable* $g(X).$

Consequently $\operatorname E(Y\mid X)=X$ is true if and only if for all values of $x,$ $\operatorname E(Y\mid X=x) = x$ is true.

In linear regression, one typically has $Y$ is an $n\times 1$ column vector, $X$ is an $n\times p$ matrix, $\beta$ is a $p\times1$ column vector, and $\operatorname E(Y\mid X) = X\beta.$ Now note that

- Often it's written as $\operatorname E(Y) = X\beta,$ and neither $X$ nor $\beta$ is treated as random. What is random is the "errors", so one has $Y=X\beta+\varepsilon,$ where $\varepsilon$ is a random $n\times 1$ column vector whose expected value is $0,$ i.e. is an $n\times1$ column of $0$s. In some problems of statistics $X$ is fixed by design, that is, the experimenter is able to choose the value of the matrix $X.$ In some other problems, it may be that the experimenter cannot choose $X$ but every time a new sample of $n$ observations is chosen, $X$ remains the same and $\beta$ remains the same, so only $\varepsilon,$ and hence $Y,$ changes. In that case, the condition is neither a random variable nor an event, but rather a parameter that determines the probability distribution of $Y.$ In all regression problems I know of, $X$ is a part of the observable data (as is $Y$) and $\beta$ is unobservable and is to be estimated based on the observation of $X$ and $Y.$ The estimate $\widehat\beta$ then becomes a random variable that one expresses as a function of $X$ and $Y.$
- But it is also often the case that whenever a new sample of $n$ observations is taken, both $X$ and $Y$ change. In that case, $X$ is a random variable and $\beta$ is not. **However,** in estimating $\beta$ by least squares in such problems, $X$ is in effect treated as not random, and the justification of that is that one is conditioning on $X.$
- Sometimes one assigns a prior probability distribution to $\beta,$ not because $\beta$ is random in the sense of being something that changes each time a new sample of $n$ observations is taken, but because the value of $\beta$ is uncertain. In that case, instead of using least squares or any of its relatives, on multiplies the likelihood function (a pointwise defined function of $\beta$) by the prior probability measure on $\beta,$ and then normalizes, to get the posterior probability distribution of $\beta.$

Comment: If $X$ is a continuous random variable (i.e. c.d.f of $X$ is a continuous function), then the event $[X=x]$ is of measure zero. The conditional expectation $E[Y\mid A]$ of a random variable $Y$ over a null event $A$ is undefined. (or at least, cannot be defined in the classical way).

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan : True, but how to condition on an event of probability $0$ didn't seem to be the actual topic in this case.

Comment: We may need to explicitly point out the following logical fallacy:

Define the conditional expectation $E[Y\mid X=x]$ as $E[Y\mid X=x] = \int_{[X=x]} Y\,dP / P([X=x])$.
Define $g(x)= E[Y\mid X=x]$, then $E[Y\mid X]$ is defined as $g(X)$.

The logical difficulty is that $\int_{[X=x]} Y\,dP / P([X=x])$ is well-defined only when $P[X=x]>0.$

The greatest probabilist Komogorov solved this problem by re-defining the definition of conditional expectation,
i.e. by defining $E[Y\mid X]$ using Radon-Nikodym Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let us state everything precisely: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be
a probability space. Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be random variables such that $E[|Y|]<\infty$. The symbol $E[Y\mid X]$
is just a short form for $E[Y\mid\sigma(X)]$. Denote $V=E[Y\mid\sigma(X)]$,
which is a $\sigma$(X)-measurable, integrable random variable such
that $\int_{A}V\,dP=\int_{A}Y\,dP$ for any $A\in\sigma(X)$. By Radon-Nikodym
Theorem, such $V$ exists and is unique a.e..

Since $V$ is $\sigma(X)$-mesurable, there exists a Borel function
$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $V=f\circ X$. (This
result is due to Doob). Note that such $f$ is not unique. Moreover,
let $\mu_{X}$ be the probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ induced
by $X$ (i.e., $\mu_{X}(B)=P[X^{-1}(B)]$, $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$).
If $f_{1},f_{2}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are Borel functions
such that both $f_{1}\circ X$ and $f_{2}\circ X$ are qualified as
the conditional expectation $E[Y\mid X]$, then $f_{1}=f_{2}$ $\mu_{X}-a.e.$

Regarding the notation $E[Y\mid X=x]$, it should be interpreted as
$E[Y\mid X=x]=f(x)$, where $f$ is a Borel fucntion such that $f\circ X$
acts as the conditional expectation $E[Y\mid X]$. Since $f$ is not
unique in pointwise sense, the discussion $E[Y\mid X=x_{0}]$ for
a particular $x_{0},$ in general, does not make sense.

Another interpretation of the symbol $E[Y\mid X=x]$ is $E[Y\mid X=x]=\int_{[X=x]}Y\,dP/P([X=x])$.
However, this makes sense only if $P([X=x])>0.$